# Programmatric Vector Construction

Tags: r

Does any one how to contruct the following vector programatically:

```
c("street" = "st", "place" = "pl" , "road" = "rd")
```

I am using it in the following context:

```
library(stringr)

vct_address <- c("20 fun street", 
          "5 neko place", 
          "23 ggplot road", 
          "7 dplyr street", 
          "9 sad place") 

vct_re <- c("street" = "st", "place" = "pl" , "road" = "rd")
stringr::str_replace_all(vct_address, vct_re)
#  "20 fun st"    "5 neko pl"    "23 ggplot rd" "7 dplyr st"   "9 sad pl"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "programatically" here - something like `abbrevs = c("st", "pl", "rd"); full = c("street", "place", "road"); setNames(abbrevs, full)`?

Comment: Thanks @Marius what you have suggusted is the general idea but setNames(x, y) will not evaluate to: c("street" = "st", "place" = "pl" , "road" = "rd") which is the form that stringr::str_replace_all() requires.

Comment: Are you sure? It creates a named vector, which is the same as what `c("street" = "st", "place" = "pl" , "road" = "rd")` does. I've just tested it in `str_replace_all()` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Oops. I restarted R.  Your correct.  Thanks heaps.